# SQL. Подсчёт кол-ва лет. DATE_FORMAT не является известным имя встроенной функции

Tags: sql, sql-server

Пытаюсь правильно посчитать кол-во лет

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableNum3](
    [Код] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [birthday] [datetime] NULL,
    [age] [int] null,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tableNum3] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(

    [Код] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SELECT birthday,
  (
    (YEAR(GETDATE) - YEAR(birthday)) - (DATE_FORMAT(GETDATE, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m%d'))
  ) AS age
FROM tableNum3
```

Выдаёт такую ошибку: 
**Сообщение 195, уровень 15, состояние 10, строка 27
DATE_FORMAT не является известным имя встроенной функции.**

Как быть, что делать?

Comment: поверить серверу в том, что такой функции у него нет. открыть документацию, и найти аналог для вашей версии sql server. возможно просто `format()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо что помогли, но всё оказалось куда проще. При создании таблицы.

```
    [birthday] [datetime] NULL,
    [age]  AS (floor(CONVERT([int],getdate()-[birthday])/(365.25))),
```

всё отлично работает

Answer (score 1):

1. В MS SQL нет прямого аналога DATE_FORMAT.
2. Еще и нет неявного преобразования Boolean в число. Выражение вида `A - (C < D)` вернет ошибку несовместимости типов. Нужно использовать `CASE`
3. Также вместо `YEAR(GETDATE())` лучше использовать стандартную функцию `DATEPART`. А данном случае еще лучше `DATEDIFF`.

Также правильное, то есть полное количество лет получается если разницу между годами скорректировать разницу с учетом того, что дата внутри года может быть до или после текущей, что и сделано у вас в примере.

Академически верное сравнение: M1 < M2 || M1 = M2 && D1 < D2

Итого получаем:

```
DATEDIFF(YEAR, birthday, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) < DATEPART(MONTH, birthday) OR DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = DATEPART(MONTH, birthday) AND DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) < DATEPART(DAY, birthday) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Для упрощения можно учесть тот факт, что для записи в формате MMDD лексикографической сравнение (как строки) соответствует сравнению дат.

Не совсем красиво можно заменить `DATE_FORMAT` с форматом '%m%d' на вызов `CONVERT` с отрезанием года: `RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112), 4)`

Тогда получим:

```
DATEDIFF(YEAR, birthday, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112), 4) < RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), birthday, 112), 4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )`

```
SELECT DATEDIFF( year , birthday, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Ваш пример работает несколько иначе. Приведенный в вопросе код показывает количество полных лет, и для дат 01.06.2019 и 28.05.2020 вернет 0, ваш же код — 1.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Тогда возьмите DATEDIFF( day , birthday, GETDATE()) / 365 и округлите так как вам надо.